# How to convert untyped Object to HashMap<String,Object>

Tags: java, hashmap

I have Hashmap of <String, Object> that could contain different object type like String, Int. So I have already successfully cast the object to int and string. But When I try to cast it into a hashmap that doesn't work and I have empty value with no error.

Here is what I have try :

```java
String str = "hey";
Int intVal= 66;
HashMap<String, String> myGetHashMapVal= new HashMap<>();

HashMap<String,Obj> objHashMap = new HashMap<>();

objHashMap.put("TheString",str);
objHashMap.put("TheInt",intVal);
objHashMap.put("HashMap",myGetHashMapVal);


HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) objHashMap.get("HashMap");
```

Comment: How are you determining that you have an empty value with no error?  You should have a valid value, but printing it would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Interesting.  Putting an instance of a hash map in itself.  That would never have occurred to me.  Not certain of the need though.

Comment: @LouisWasserman beacose I have use my debugger and in my debuger the object apear as HashMap

Comment: @WJS I need it for some recursive treatment when I recall function that use hashmap.

Comment: Shouldn't `HashMap<String,Obj> objHashMap = new HashMap<>()` be `HashMap<String,Object> ...`

Comment: @WJS yes ^^' I have modified my show code (I don't have do that in my app code)

Comment: I don't understand how you can put an instance of multiple API types in a hash map whose values are of type `Obj`.  Are you using some special library?  If so can you add it to your tags?

Comment: Putting different types of unrelated objects into a collection is usually a bad idea in object oriented languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this works just fine for me.

```
HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("myMap", map);
map.put("int", 1);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashMap<String,Object> map2 = (HashMap<String,Object>)map.get("myMap");
System.out.println(map2.get("int"));
```

Prints

```
1
```